# UNION changes the order in the query. Why?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a problem with a specific task on hackerrank:
https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/the-pads/problem?isFullScreen=true

I know how to do it, but for some reason UNION break the query for me.

If I write this:

```
(select concat(name,substring(occupation,1,1)) from occupations
order by name)
```

and this:

```
(select concat('There are a total of ',count(occupation),' ', occupation,'s.') 
from occupations
group by occupation
order by count(occupation),occupation)
```

Result are ok and the order is correct.

However when I want to combine these two select with UNION  (or UNION ALL) it break the order. Why is that? how can I preserve the order?

```
 (select concat(name,substring(occupation,1,1)) from occupations
order by name)

UNION ALL

(select concat('There are a total of ',count(occupation),' ', occupation,'s.') from occupations
group by occupation
order by count(occupation),occupation)
```

Result from query with UNION:

```
AshleyP
SamanthaA
JuliaD
BritneyP

...
There are a total of 7 Professors.
There are a total of 4 Actors.
There are a total of 3 Doctors.
There are a total of 4 Singers.
```

Now if I do it seperately:

Results from first select :

```
AaminaD
AshleyP
BelvetP
...
```

Result from second select:

```
There are a total of 3 Doctors.
There are a total of 4 Actors.
There are a total of 4 Singers.
There are a total of 7 Professors.
```

Comment: The two halves of the union query appear to be the same, did you make a mistake?

Comment: also add a [mre] not every one has access

Comment: Sorry. My bad. I updated the post.

Answer (score 1):

Putting an ORDER BY in the individual SELECT statements has no impact of the order of rows in the final resultset (or, at least, you cannot guarantee what the impact will be or that the order will remain the same if you run the statement multiple times).

If you want to order the resultset then you need an ORDER BY clause at the end and you would need column(s) with values that allow you to order in the way that you want. For example, if you want to order by each individual SELECT statement and then by a column within each SELECT statement you could do something like this:

```
SELECT 1 AS col1, A AS col2
FROM table1
UNION
SELECT 2, B
FROM table2
ORDER BY col1, col2
```

Answer (score 0):

add a sort column.

```
SELECT * FROM (
select 1 as sort, 'foo' as c1 from T1
union all
select 2 as sort, 'bar' as c1 from T1
) as T0
ORDER BY sort
```